# Create a "Dummy" parent page for a hierarchy in page listing?

Tags: pages, wp-admin, child-pages

**Is it possible to set up a "dummy" page - just a page title that appears in the page listing, and a page that is not editable and doesn't have a slug?**

This is more of a hypothetical question, as I don't know where to start with code or determine the best way to go.

I'd like to have the option to set up such a parent/child hierarchy in the page listing so that the child pages fall under the parent, but the parent page is just a placeholder and not a real page.

The reason: for users without lots of experience in WordPress, it's helpful to organize pages in a parent/child hierarchy - especially if there are lots of pages - so that that related pages are more organized in the page listing. Users can also visualize building a menu, too, if child pages are organized under a parent. The problem is the parent page can be editable and not part of the established page content, and in my experience, this leads to user confusion.

I can use a function to remove the editor for a specific page and use entires in robots.txt to not index the dummy parent, but that means changing those for a new parent. And that parent page still has a slug, even if blocked wit

*So is there a way to create a function that creates a page title and with the ability to assign child pages, but have the parent page unopenable, uneditable and not have a slug?*

[image]

Comment: "... a page title and with the ability to assign child pages, but have the parent page unopenable, uneditable and not have a slug?" -- sounds a lot like a custom post type.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to remove the slug. I forgot if you can show it in the admin but hide it from the front-end, if so you can use some javascript in the back-end to remove the link.

Comment: You can try and set `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'false'` for the CPT or set it to `/` or `#`, worth a try

Comment: s_ha_dum and Wyck: CPT, good idea; I'll look into that. So non-CPT pages - regular WP pages - can be children of a CPT?

Comment: I don't think so without some major hacking around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK here is my attempt, it is pretty hacky and in the end I was not able to remove the link/color of the parent item, but the parent link will not work.. so it kinda works.

First create a CPT with the following params set:

```
$args = array( 
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post', 
        'supports'            => array( 'title','page-attributes' ),
    );
```

Fill in the rest as needed, this will enable you to have a parent post/page that shows in the admin but not on the front end, it also allows parent functionality via `page-attributes`.

Now we can throw in a filter that removes the small *"edit", "view" and "trash"* links for the parent.

```
function wpse_95518($actions) {

    global $post;

    //rename this to your CPT 
    if ($post->post_type =="parent"){
        // check if it's a parent
        if ( ! (is_post_type_hierarchical('parent') && $post->post_parent )) {

            unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
            unset( $actions['trash'] );
            unset( $actions['view'] );  
            unset( $actions['edit'] );
        }           
        return $actions;
    }
    return $actions; 
}

add_filter('page_row_actions', 'wpse_95518');
```

Now things get a bit funky, to remove the parent title link functionality to edit the post.

```
function wpse_removetitle_95518($action){

    global $post; 

    if ($post->post_type =="parent"){
        if ( is_post_type_hierarchical('parent') && $post->post_parent ) {
            return $action;
        }else{
            return '#'; //just in case
        }
    }
    return $action;
 }
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', 'wpse_removetitle_95518');
```

Now parent items of the CPT should not be editable via links in the admin, it will show as `edit.php?post_type=parent#` but the children will be ok.

The downside is that the parent item will still be a blue link instead of black text, I could not find any simple way to remove the link from the title or add custom CSS to do it via javascript without extending the `WP List Table`.

You can of course alter the parent title using `the_title` filter but even setting it to `NULL` via the above conditional still shows a `< a href=..>`

Also there might be a simpler way to do all of this just using the `is_post_type_hierarchical` filter.

[Github link to Table Class](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L518) code for the title.

Comment: Thanks for all this; it's appreciated. But if non-CPT pages - regular WP pages - can't be children of a CPT, I guess I'd have to change the pages to CPTs. The thing I did for now was make blank parent pages and block them in robots.txt; and then use custom links in the menu with http://# to not use the parents in the menu.