# Restrict access to post if it is currently being edited

Tags: posts, php, editor, limit, content-restriction

On a platform with many Editors, the problem that I am experiencing is that two editors proofread the same post simultaneously (and disregarding the warning notice about someone else currently editing the post).

Is there a solution where I can restrict access to a post if it is currently being edited by a different user? Maybe by disabling the post's edit link on the post list? This should only take effect on editors if they are not the author of the post (we don't want them to be locked out of their own post) and admins should be excluded from any restriction.

Comment: Btw, post forking is in too early stages: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/post-forking

Comment: Curious: what happens if an editor is editing a post, and then the post's author or admin wants to go and modify it?

Comment: Editors are only allowed to edit *pending* posts, so the conflict happens between editors themselves and occasionally admins. So if two editors proofread the same post, then one of them wasted time. Do you get my drift?

Comment: Not that it's of any help at the moment, but it looks like they are working on a solution for this in 3.6 http://make.wordpress.org/core/2013/01/07/wordpress-3-6-autosave-and-post-locking/

Comment: I did read about the local autosave feature but didn't know about the possible post locking one. I wonder how this function will work.

Comment: It really needed as WP evolved into a nice CMS. Still I hope it will be permission based and not something that users need to activate them selfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning notice gets dispatched by the function `wp_check_post_lock`. The following redirects the user back to the post listing screen if someone else is editing it.

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'redirect_locked_post_wpse_95718' );

function redirect_locked_post_wpse_95718()
{
    if( isset($_GET['post'] ) && wp_check_post_lock( $_GET['post'] ) )
    {
        global $typenow;
        $goto = ( 'post' == $typenow ) ? '' : "?post_type=$typenow";
        wp_redirect( admin_url( "edit.php$goto" ) );
        exit();
    }
}
```

And to indicate that a post is locked, ie, being edited by other user, a small red sign can be added to the row actions.

[image: locked post]

```
foreach( array( 'post', 'page' ) as $hook )
    add_filter( "{$hook}_row_actions", 'locked_post_notice_wpse_95718', 10, 2 );

function locked_post_notice_wpse_95718( $actions, $post ) 
{
    if( wp_check_post_lock( $post->ID ) )
    {
        $actions['locked'] = sprintf(
            '<span style="color:#f00;font-weight:bolder;">&#149;&#149;&#149; LOCKED %s &#149;&#149;&#149;</span>',
            strtoupper( $post->post_type )
        );
    }
    return $actions; 
}
```

Comment: Two questions before I start testing this stellar answer. Is admins excluded from this lockout? And if someone is editing a post, can the **author** of the post still access it?

Comment: No, no user/role is being considered. It's just a base that needs refinement :) - You'd have to check against current user and `post_author`.

Comment: And it is a great base indeed, thank you brasofilo! Exactly what I needed. Particularly the indicator solution. I will test this and report back if there are any issues.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the `Locked` note at the beginning of the post title instead? Like this for instance: http://i.imgur.com/bmzwUMI.png

Comment: You can filter `the_title`, [this example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/72982/12615) gives an idea. Maybe add the filter inside `load-post.php` action.

Comment: Interesting filter (`get_edit_post_link`) in [this Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/95664/12615).

Comment: Thank you brasofilo, I will review this at the office tomorrow!